# Xcode - How to get iPhone 11 Simulator for development?

Tags: iphone, simulator, xcode11

I want to get iPhone 11 Simulator in my Xcode for development. How it can achieve if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhone 11/Pro/Pro Max simulators are available in the Xcode 11 GM seeds 1 and 2